# R deepnet package: how to add more hidden layers to my neural network?

Tags: r, neural-network, deep-learning, r-package

I just started to study the "deepnet" package:
http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/deepnet/index.html

It is about "deep leaning", so about the usage of multi-layer neural networks.
I've started to use the train() functions available in the package,
but I really cannot understand how to add more hidden layers in the
neural networks.
The standard setting includes 2 hidden layers, but I would like to add more, like 5.
Does some of you have an idea?

I am using the sae.dnn.train() function but I cannot understand which
parameter controls the number of hidden layers.
Here's the example code:

```
Var1 <- c(rnorm(50, 1, 0.5), rnorm(50, -0.6, 0.2))
Var2 <- c(rnorm(50, -0.8, 0.2), rnorm(50, 2, 1))
x <- matrix(c(Var1, Var2), nrow = 100, ncol = 2)
y <- c(rep(1, 50), rep(0, 50))
dnn <- sae.dnn.train(x, y, hidden = c(5, 5))
## predict by dnn
test_Var1 <- c(rnorm(50, 1, 0.5), rnorm(50, -0.6, 0.2))
test_Var2 <- c(rnorm(50, -0.8, 0.2), rnorm(50, 2, 1))
test_x <- matrix(c(test_Var1, test_Var2), nrow = 100, ncol = 2)
nn.test(dnn, test_x, y)
```

Which parameter sets the number of hidden layers in the neural network?
How to add more hidden layers?

Comment: btw, `h2o` is really fast w/ high usability and you can try it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although I am unfamiliar with the `deepnet` package, it appears it is structured the same as other neural net packages.  After looking at the documentation (`?sae.dnn.train`) you will see:

```
hidden:    vector for number of units of hidden layers.Default is c(10).
```

Now this isn't the clearest description but I believe it supposed to be the same as the `neuralnet` function in the `neuralnet` package. `?neural::neuralnet`

```
hidden:    a vector of integers specifying the number of hidden neurons 
           (vertices) in each layer.
```

This is much more clear where you can understand that you are creating a vector specifying the number of neurons (nodes, vertices, etc.) in each **layer**.

So, to sum up, your example with `hidden = c(5, 5)` is for **two layers with 5 neurons in each layer**.  So if you wanted 5 hidden layers with 5 neurons in each you would simply put `hidden = c(5, 5, 5, 5, 5)`.

Comment: Thanks @cdeterman. I modified my example, and yes, that seems to be the parameter for the number of layers, but it does not seem to work with more than three layers. That is ``dnn <- sae.dnn.train(x, y, hidden = c(5, 5, 5)`` works; but ``dnn <- sae.dnn.train(x, y, hidden = c(5, 5, 5, 5))`` gives error: "Error in sae$encoder[[i - 1]]$B[[i - 1]] : subscript out of bounds". Any idea on on how to solve this?

Comment: That appears to be a bug in the code for models with many layers.  You can look at the code yourself at the github page [here](https://github.com/cran/deepnet/tree/master/R) where the error appears to be happening at line 32 in the sae_train.R file .  It would probably be best to contact the package maintainer.  Although I don't know the exact differences between the packages, the `neuralnet::neuralnet` function does work with more than 3 layers if you also want to explore that avenue.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if ``neuralnets`` package includes the Dropout training?

Comment: @DavideChicco.it I am not certain about the Dropout training, I suspect not as there is no explicit documentation saying otherwise.  Again, likely best option would be to contact that package maintainer too (didn't realize your requirement) or look into the method and contribute to the package :).  Lastly,   I just stumbled on [this question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/41771/r-libraries-for-deep-learning) on SE regarding the `darch` package.  It doesn't appear to be as user friendly but perhaps a last alternative if you don't want to do more source coding.